# I want to set a radio button as checked in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to StackOverflow so apologies if I am not giving enough information. I have a booklist that am sorting with AngularJS. I have 4 radio buttons that work fine to filter the results by category, but I want "SciFi" to be selected by default. I can't get the examples I have found in stackoverflow to work.

These are my 4 radio buttons:

```
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.category" value="" /> All 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.category" value="SciFi" /> SciFi 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.category" value="Horror" /> Horror 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.category" value="Fantasy" /> Fantasy
```

This is the div that runs my ng-repeat:

```
    <div class="booklistData resultsExist" ng-repeat="book in booklist | orderBy:sort:reverse | filter:search as results">
```

I tried ng-checked on the SciFi radio button like this:

```
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.category" ng-value="SciFi" ng-checked="(search.category == SciFi)" />
```

but it disables all the radio buttons.

As a test I even tried to add the filter to the ng-repeat div like this but without success either:

```
    <div class="booklistData resultsExist" ng-repeat="book in booklist | orderBy:sort:reverse | filter:{category:SciFi}">
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Adding the Controller code here. Sorry I should have done that first.

```
    var app = angular.module('booklistApp', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.controller('getBooklist', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("booklist-app.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.booklist = response.data;}); 
    $scope.sort = "bknumber*1";
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.changeSort = function(value){
    if ($scope.sort == value){
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    return;
    }
    $scope.sort = value;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    }
    $scope.selectedSort = 1;
    });
```

Comment: You just have to verify that the variable search.category is correctly set. Use `<pre>{{ search | json }}</pre>` to debug the template in which you are. You have to put in your controller `scope.search.category = 'SciFi'`.

Comment: Just set `search.category` by default to `SciFi ` radio buttons gets selected when the ng-model match the radio value and do not use ng-checked with ng-model (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `map` function on the array.

The `map` code is as follows.

```
$scope.booklist = $scope.booklist.map(function(x){
    if(x.category === ''){
        x.category = "SciFi";
    }
    return x;
  });
```

We check if the category is blank or not, if its blank we assign the value `'SciFi'` else we assign back the original value to `book.category`.

***Note: I think its better to not use `ng-init` or `ng-checked` because on filtering the directives will get triggered again and you will loose the previous values that were already set!***

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.booklist = [{
    name: "harry potter 1",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 1
  }, {
    name: "harry potter 2",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 2
  }, {
    name: "harry potter 3",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 3
  }, {
    name: "harry potter 4",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 4
  }, {
    name: "harry potter 5",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 5
  }, {
    name: "harry potter 6",
    category: '',
    bknumber: 6
  }];
  $scope.booklist = $scope.booklist.map(function(x) {
    if (x.category === '') {
      x.category = "SciFi";
    }
    return x;
  });
  $scope.sort = "bknumber*1";
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.changeSort = function(value) {
    if ($scope.sort == value) {
      $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
      return;
    }
    $scope.sort = value;
    $scope.reverse = false;
  }
  $scope.selectedSort = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <button ng-click="changeSort('bknumber*1')">toggle Sort</button>
  <div class="booklistData resultsExist" ng-repeat="book in booklist | orderBy:sort:reverse | filter:search as results">
    {{book.name}}
    <input type="radio" ng-model="book.category" value="" /> All
    <input type="radio" ng-model="book.category" value="SciFi" /> SciFi
    <input type="radio" ng-model="book.category" value="Horror" /> Horror
    <input type="radio" ng-model="book.category" value="Fantasy" /> Fantasy
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Randy I don't get what you mean by the above comment, can you explain more?

Comment: @Randy The code seems fine! after adding the changes, please implement my code changes and let me know what the issues is you are facing!

Comment: I get an error - Error: $scope.booklist is undefined

Comment: @Randy Can you share a JSFiddle with the error, so that I can assist you, must be a minor issue only!

Comment: If I add $scope.search.category = 'SciFi'; I also get Error: $scope.search is undefined. Do the categories need to be defined first? I thought starting with a default category would not be hard, but I am definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: @Randy If you could share a JSFiddle right with the problem will give you the solution, basically category needs to be defined, can you also share the structure of the object that is used in the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: My radio buttons are outside the NG-repeat. I am not sure if that makes a difference. I added a JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ernt1hae/ but sorry I don't know how to get the data that comes from mysql. I guess I would have to show an example of the JSON of 10 records or so?